# wait until page is loaded function in intern 4 using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, intern

I have some how implemented the function to wait until page is loaded in [intern 4](https://theintern.io) with `TypeScript`. But some times it dosen't work and throws `TimeOutEror` even if i catch the error in the function. Can some one please review and tell me whats wrong with it.

Heres my implementation:

```
  export abstract class AdvalentBasePage {
    remote: any;
    waitTime: number = -1;
    locator: any;

    constructor(remote: any, locator: any) {
        this.remote = remote;
        this.locator =locator ;

    }

    abstract  getPageTitleXpath(): string;


    getPageTitleElement() {
        return this.remote.findByXpath(this.getPageTitleXpath());
    }

      //this function sometimes throws timeoutError even before waitTime provided in argument
    async waitUntilPageIsFullyLoaded(waitTime: number): Promise<any> {

        this.waitTime = waitTime;
        var self = this;
        try {
            await self.remote.sleep(1000).findByXpath(self.getPageTitleXpath());
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.name)
            if (e.name == 'NoSuchElement') {
                if (this.waitTime > 0) {
                    self.waitTime = self.waitTime - 1000;
                    await self.waitUntilPageIsFullyLoaded(self.waitTime);
                }
                else {
                    throw new Error('TimeOut Exception  ')
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different timeouts in play:

1. The async test timeout -- Intern will timeout if a test takes longer than this (30 seconds by default), regardless of what the test is doing.
2. The find timeout -- a `findBy` call will timeout if an element isn't found within this time (browser-dependent, typically 0 by default)

It's not clear from your description what the specific error is, although it sounds like you may be running into a general test timeout error. You can get around that by increasing the test timeout (`this.timeout = x` or `this.async(x)` in a test, where x is a number of milliseconds).

It looks like you could also simplify your approach by simply setting a very large find timeout rather than creating the `waitUntilPageIsFullLoaded` method. For example (assuming `self` is pointing to the Test object):

```
// Make sure the test timeout is large enough to handle the time
// required to run all test actions.
self.timeout = 130000;

await self.remote
    // Set the find timeout to something huge; this is still efficient
    // because the test will continue as soon as an element is found
    .setFindTimeout(120000)
    .sleep(1000)
    .findByXpath(self.getPageTitleXpath())
```